# Calling wrong template function prototype problem in c++

Tags: c++, templates

I am currently making my custom vector container for understanding better the real STL containers. I am confront with the problem of "insert" function.

These are two prototypes of "insert" in my vector container.

```cpp
// 1
template <typename T, typename Alloc>
void vector<T, Alloc>::insert(iterator position, size_type n, const value_type &val)

// 2
template <typename T, typename Alloc>
template <class InputIterator>
void vector<T, Alloc>::insert(iterator position, InputIterator first, InputIterator last)
```

When I try to use insert function in main.cpp like below,

```cpp
int main() {
    ft::vector<int> my;
    my.insert(my.begin(), 5, 6); <-- it calls second proto.
    return (0);
}
```

I intended to call first prototype but it calls second one which is for iterator params...
Could you please explain me why it happens and how to solve it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use some SFINAE to restrict the `InputIterator` overload to iterator types.

Assuming your iterator adheres to `iterator_traits` and/or has a nested type like `iterator_category`, you can check for its presence via SFINAE:

```
template <class Iter>
using iter_cat_t = typename iterator_traits<Iter>::iterator_category;

template <class T, class = void>
constexpr bool is_iterator_v = false;

template <class T>
constexpr bool is_iterator_v<T, std::void_t<iter_cat_t<T>>> = true;

template <typename T, typename Alloc>
template <class InputIterator, std::enable_if_t<is_iterator_v<InputIterator>, int> = 0>
void vector<T, Alloc>::insert(iterator position, InputIterator first, InputIterator last)
```

Comment: Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

The line :

```
my.insert(my.begin(), 5, 6); <-- it calls second proto.
```

will deduce  `InputIterator` to `int` and it will be a perfect match. Instead the first function will have to convert the `int` into `size_type` and `value_type` (probably not int)

You should use `SFINAE` to restrict the second for types which match `InputIterator` concept, so only the first one will be considered.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation :)

Comment: No problem, don't hesitate to up-vote any useful answer, specially the one you accepted

Answer (score 0):

```
int main() {
    ft::vector<int> my;
    my.insert(my.begin(), 5u, 6); <-- it calls the first prototype.
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: True, but what about `ft::vector<size_type> ...`?