# How can I use my custom enable_if in c++98?

Tags: c++, templates, c++98

I am currently making custom Vector container for the purpose of studying. My assignment has limitation that i should use c++98 version.

But during the implementation of "insert" function, i have problem which i explained in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61550311/calling-wrong-template-function-prototype-problem-in-c?noredirect=1#comment108876813_61550311).

I got some hints that i should use "enable_if" from link. But because I have no right to use c++11 (enable_if defined) extention so i made enable if and is_integral by myself.

This is previous one.

```cpp
// 1
template <typename T, typename Alloc>
void vector<T, Alloc>::insert(iterator position, size_type n, const value_type &val)

// 2
template <typename T, typename Alloc>
template <class InputIterator>
void vector<T, Alloc>::insert(iterator position, InputIterator first, InputIterator last)
```

This is the code that i changed with custom enable_if and is_integral

```cpp
// 1
template <typename T, typename Alloc>
void vector<T, Alloc>::insert(iterator position, size_type n, const value_type &val)

// 2
template <typename T, typename Alloc>
template <class InputIterator, class  = typename ft::enable_if<!ft::is_integral<InputIterator>::value>::type>
void vector<T, Alloc>::insert(iterator position, InputIterator first, InputIterator last)
```

It works well if i don't give "-std=c++98" option to compiler, 
but if i give it, it said

```
./Vector.hpp:87:33: warning: default template arguments for a function template are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
  ...class  = typename ft::enable_if<!ft::is_integral<InputIterator>::value>::type>
     ^
```

Could you please help me to adapt my code for c++98 extension ?

Comment: [Use boost](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/core/doc/html/core/enable_if.html). It should work with C++98 compilers, or at least see how they have accomplished implementing these templates.

Comment: I have no right to use boost neither.

Comment: Oh, good idea. Thanks!

Comment: The teacher is not looking over your shoulder when you are experimenting.  Use `boost` first to see if indeed their `enable_if` and `is_integral` works for your C++98 project.  Once you have confirmed it works, then look to see what they are doing to implement those templates.

Comment: BTW, those parts of boost that implement those templates are header-only files.  This means that all you have to do is have the proper `#include` files for boost and see if your code compiles (and works).

Answer (score 1):

enable_if it's a c++11 option, but you can implement it in the c++98 way by following the next :

first let's create the enable_if struct :

```
template<bool, class T>    //i give it two parameters, up to you to give more or less
struct enable_if
{};

template <class T>
struct enable_if<true, T>
{
    typedef T value;     //if true define the T type value
};
```

second (optional) we need an enable_if option to work with i've choose the **is_integral** one, let's implement it :

```
template <class T, T v>
struct integral_constant   //integral C++ struct in C++98 manner
{
    typedef T value_type;
    typedef integral_constant<T,v> type;
    static const T value = v;
    operator T() { return value; }
};

typedef integral_constant<bool,true> true_type;
typedef integral_constant<bool,false> false_type;

template<typename T>
struct is_integral : public false_type{};
    
template<>
struct is_integral<char> : public true_type{};
```

now our c++98 enable_if is ready to use with is_integral option

finally your reimplement insert function will work by adding enable_if to it :

```
void insert (iterator position, InputIterator first, InputIterator last, typename ft::enable_if<!ft::is_integral<InputIterator>::value, InputIterator>::value* = nullptr)
```

Answer (score -2):

`std::enable_if` and `std::is_integral` were introduced in C++11. You can reimplement them like that if you compile with the `--std=c++98` flag.

You can find all the specifications to do that [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/is_integral/?kw=is_integral) and [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/29824521)

Comment: @Yun: Why do you say that?

Comment: @JeremyCaney This came from a review task, and this was the "closest match" comment I could click on. What I really meant to add is - How does this answer the question "Hoe can I use my custom enable_if?" or "How can I adapt my code  to be C++98?" OP already stated that enable_if and is_integral were part of C++11. "You can reimplement...", well yes, but _how_?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Yun. I'm working on the same project and i know that one of its objectives is to use cplusplus.com and cppreference.com to find all the specifications of the traits. And thats why i shouldn't give him infos about how its done! I added the links to the specs though

Comment: @wpark and Med.Bouzaien, are you sure you are not violating the course's policy by asking for or providing help here?

Comment: @Yun no, we even have a Stackoverflow network